# Iterate over infinispan Cache object

Tags: loops, caching, infinispan, distributed-caching

I am using the infinispan cache map in a java project to store my values in **key/value** format.

**Can we iterate over these cache map like we iterate java Maps.**

I need these cache map values/keys later for different operations.

Answer (score 2):

Of course! [Here's an example](https://github.com/infinispan/infinispan-simple-tutorials/blob/master/distributed/src/main/java/org/infinispan/tutorial/simple/distributed/InfinispanDistributed.java#L29).